# Automatically updating file views from http log into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, lighttpd

I log image views inside mysql (but only when someone sees it from the webpage, I can't access it when they look at domain.com/image.jpg, the raw image file). So I can use this to retrieve the image views and update them into mysql:

```
cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | grep "ae.jpg" | wc -l
```

I run a mysql query to get all the images on the server and run that command for each file, then update each field, this won't be possible when I get more images, I need to figure out how to automate this with a bash file and make it so it doesn't have to read all the files from mysql first.

How could I go about doing this? I just need it to update every image view counter in mysql about each hour (there will be about 100k+ images, but not all of them will get views each hour)

Comment: cron job ? there are  many log analysis packages

Comment: to get the count for `ae.jpg`, you could have said `grep -c "ae\.jpg" /var/log/lighttpd/acces.log`, please post some sample access log entries